# Enabling FIPS on google compute engine instance

Tags: centos, google-compute-engine, rhel, fips

In trying to get `FIPS` enabled on a `CentOS` instance that is already up and running, I've looked at both `RHEL` documentation and `gcloud`'s limited documentation, but to no avail.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Security_Guide/chap-Federal_Standards_and_Regulations.html#sec-Enabling-FIPS-Mode

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/building-images simply points you to https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gcrypt/Enabling-FIPS-mode.html

`/proc/sys/crypto/fips_enabled` exists, w/ a numeric value of `0`, but cannot be edited, even by `root`.

Has anyone been able to enable `FIPS`?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to enable FIPS mode on both RHEL7 and CentOS7 instances on GCE by following the [guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Security_Guide/chap-Federal_Standards_and_Regulations.html#sec-Enabling-FIPS-Mode) you have mentioned.

```
[root@fips-centos ~]# cat /proc/sys/crypto/fips_enabled 
1
```

Note that values in proc cannot be always simply edited. For this particular change you need to modify kernel boot parameters and reboot the instance to see configuration in effect.

Try to follow the guide to the letter and I am sure you will be able to enable FIPS mode.